# What does "Only" mean in "Only don't tell anyone"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Harry Potter:

> Ron was so amazed, so impressed, he just sat and gaped at Harry.
>
> “I start training next week,” said Harry. “**Only** don’t tell anyone,
>   Wood wants to keep it a secret.”

What does "only" mean here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this sentence, only is used as a conjunction.

From the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/only):

> **conjunction** *informal*
>
> Except that; but.
>
> ‘he is still a young man, only he seems older because of his careworn expression’
>    ‘the place was like school, only better’

In the text the sentence is broken up by "said Harry."  What Harry actually said was: "I start training next week.  Only don't tell anyone, Wood wants to keep it a secret."

You can see more about conjunctions, including starting a sentence with a conjunction, [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/conjunctions).